# Sorting dates in sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have developed an App ..For that  I have a database and it has many tables. One of the table has date column.
My question is I have to sort the dates and have to pick oldest one Like ***Oct-24-2012*** from below table column

Column_Date
------------

Nov-07-2012
Nov-21-2012
Nov-25-2012
Oct-25-2012
Oct-24-2102

How should I do that....I have stored the date column in string... If I need to change the datatype for date Column, Let me know which Datatype should i used. And How Should I sort the Column.According to That datatype..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In sqlite does not really have a date type. You can store dates as strings using one of their predefined formats see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html for more information.

A time string can be in any of the following formats:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

You need to store them in YYYY-MM-DD then you can sort them order by asc limit 1 to get the oldest date.
So instead of

```
Column_Date
------------
Nov-07-2012
Nov-21-2012
Nov-25-2012
Oct-25-2012
Oct-24-2102
```

You will have to store them like this instead

```
Column_Date
------------
2012-11-07
2012-11-21
2012-11-25
2012-10-25
2012-10-24
```

Finally you read the rows if any

```
Cursor oldestDateCursor = db.query("DateTableName", null, null, null, null, null, "date_column ASC LIMIT 1");
if (oldestDateCursor.moveToFirst())
{
    String date = oldestDateCursor.getColumnName(oldestDateCursor.getColumnIndex("date_column"));
}
oldestDateCursor.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have one more doubt,If I wanna put the date in sorted form is there anyway to do it... like user can enter the date any time ,but the table should be in sorted form and also i am using list to show the dates he/she has entered ..in sorted form ....do u know any solution? ...I have an idea like first read the table in sorted form and using same cursor retrieve the data and update the same table ...

Comment: you should insert into the database and do a re fetch with the order by.. you can't just insert while sorting the fastest is to use a index on the date column

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer it helped me so much

Answer (score 4):

You can change how it is being stored. Instead of one column, have 3:

month , day , year ;

This allows more flexibilityand you can sort it more easily. Since it is numbers month(1-12) instead of strings, it will be more easily sorted.

```
SELECT month,day,year
FROM tables
ORDER BY month,day,year DESC;
```

Comment: simple and best solution

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot store the type "date" in sqlite. I'm sure that there are plenty of equally laudable ways of achieving this but here's how i personally do what you're asking. I convert all my dates to this string format: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");` I put that into my database. It's convenient and i hope for self-evident reasons. And when i want to return my dates, i simply use an order in the query like `"date DESC"`. then i reconvert it to whatever format i needed them in.